# SSH to another machine connected to VPN

Tags: networking, ssh, openvpn

This seems to be asked quite a lot but I'm not really sure how I can get this to work. I have a VPN server running OpenVPN (droplet in Digital Ocean).

I've recently set `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in sysctl.conf (just trying out after I saw a few answers here as well).

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 machine connected through VPN using Gnome NetworkManager. This has OpenSSH installed as well. I've disabled UFW for testing purposes.

I have MacOS machine connected through VPN using TunnelBlick. I am trying to SSH to the Ubuntu machine using `<user>@172.27.232.7`.

I saw this using `ifconfig`:

```
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.232.7  netmask 255.255.248.0  destination 172.27.232.7
        inet6 fe80::9b89:5fe:93e:2157  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 526848  bytes 696164111 (696.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 112098  bytes 19237139 (19.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 406 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I am just getting `ssh: connect to host 172.27.232.7 port 22: Operation timed out`. I also can't `ping` the Ubuntu machine. SSH is working fine when using LAN but not when trying to do it in through the VPN. Any clues what I might be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Enable `client-to-client` in the OpenVPN server.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Can't believe how easy it was.. :(